# how to add image to the location over a map (windows phone 8)

Tags: windows-phone-8

i am following the example
[Nokia blog](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Map_with_directions_in_Windows_Phone_8) but my problem is ,

1> i need to add image to the location point instead of color

2> i want to show detail information in the popup like Google map

Comment: ok, so show us your effort so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you.
Here i had use textblock to show custom data. Background image for a stack panel

```
      Private void ShoeCustomPushPuin()
{
            Pushpin pushPin = null;
            StackPanel stackPanel = null;
            TextBlock txtblkDownloadSpeed = null;
            TextBlock txtblkUploadSpeed = null;
            GeoCoordinate cordinates = null;

            try
            {
                cordinates = new GeoCoordinate();
                pushPin = new Pushpin();
                stackPanel = new StackPanel();
                txtblkDownloadSpeed = new TextBlock();

                txtblkUploadSpeed = new TextBlock();
                cordinates.Latitude = Your latitude value;
                cordinates.Longitude = your longitude value;
                txtblkUploadSpeed.Text = your data;
                txtblkDownloadSpeed.Text =your data;
                ImageBrush imgbrush= new ImageBrush
                    {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your background image path",     UriKind.Relative)),
            };

                stackPanel.Background = imgbrush;

                stackPanel.Children.Add(txtblkDownloadSpeed);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(txtblkUploadSpeed);
                pushPin.Content = stackPanel;
                pushPin.GeoCoordinate = cordinates;

                MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay
                {
                    GeoCoordinate = cordinates,
                    Content = pushPin
                };

                MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
                layer.Add(overlay);
                mapHistory.Center = cordinates;
                mapHistory.Layers.Add(layer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
}
```